# Handling dynamic url using curl php

Tags: php, curl

I want to grab some data from a website. I have login credential and I am able to login via curl, but there is a 2nd stage of login process where I have to answer one security question.

Problem is every-time I am entering user-id, password it redirect to different url.

As example:
Login url : https://url.com
After login: https://url?execution=e4s1&action=caDevicePrint (Security q/a page)

Here 'execution=e4s1' is changing every-time after login like e1s1, e1s2, e3s2.

I want to set CURLOPT_URL dynamically. below is my code:

```
    $this->curl = curl_init();      
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://url?execution=e4s1&action=caDevicePrint"); 
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$this->userAgent);       
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$this->cookieFile);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$this->cookieFile);

    $results = curl_exec($this->curl);
    echo $results;
    if (curl_errno($this->curl)) { 
        echo "Failed loading <br>";
        var_dump(curl_error($this->curl));
        die();
    }

    curl_close($this->curl);
```

Comment: you don't say HOW the redirect works, tell us that, and we may be of more help. is it a http 300x `Location: ` redirect? `<meta>` refresh redirect? javascript redirect? we can't answer this question accurately without this info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to grab the headers.  This will tell `curl` to include the headers in its response.

```
curl_setopt( $this->curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE );
```

Once you have the headers, you can parse through them to see what the URL is that the site is redirecting you to.

Comment: OP doesn't say how the redirect work. this would work if the redirect is based on headers.. if it's a standard HTTP (300x) redirect, `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` would suffice, though, then curl follows http 300x redirects automatically.... but until OP tells us how the redirect work, we can only assume.. for example, if its a javascript-based redirect, this won't help at all :P